# Passing arguments via command line with MPI

Tags: c++, mpi

I am using MPI calls to run a procedure on multiple processes using c++.
The first few lines in my Main function look like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int comm_sz;
int my_rank;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

x = atoi(argv[4]);
y = atoi(argv[5]);
```

Now when I execute and run my program using

```
mpiexec -n 1 program 10 10
```

I want x and y to be assigned the values 10 and 10, as they are the 4 and 5th arguments passed.
But this isn't happening and it assigns these variables to 0 and 0 accordingly. and my program does not run as desired.

I have my serial code running when I change these numbers. Its just that I am new to MPI.

Can you suggest where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried simply printing the contents of `argv`? What's the result?

Comment: I did. When I printed out the contents in the array, it did recognize the two arguments 10, 10 but not at positions 4 and 5.

Comment: It seems to be reading them as argv[1] and argv[2]. I solved my problem yes, but I wanted to know why is this happening. I am not exactly understanding MPI_Init.

Comment: When I printed out the other two arguments argv[4] and argv[5], arguments are : OMPI_MCA_orte_precondition_transports=70175593b8f2c60b-4d521364633b88b3 and this:  OMPI_MCA_rds=proxy

Comment: Here's one way to think about it: in the command you provided, the two 10 values are not at positions 4 and 5, they are at 1 and 2.  When you run `mpiexec`, it parses its arguments and sees that you wish to run `program 10 10` on all the machines in the cluster.  mpiexec can also append extra arguments (such as these OpenMPI values you are seeing), but the call to `MPI_Init` will modify `argc` and `argv` to make this invisible (see Jonathan Dursi's answer).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In most MPI implementations on Linux/Windows/Mac OSX, when you call `MPI_Init(&argc, &argv)`, the argument list is modified just as if you had run the serial problem as `program 10 10`; it eats the argument list up to the executable, which can potentially contain any number of options to the mpirun command itself.

The standard doesn't specify this; the standard leaves a lot of things about launching processes and the initialization process somewhat vague, as MPI has to work on systems that behave very differently than POSIX-type systems.   But I've never seen an MPI implementation in a POSIX-type environment that doesn't do this.

(Updated to add:) g.inozemtsev 's comment on the question is an excellent, concise explanation as to *why* this happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<mpi.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int comm_sz;
int my_rank;
int x,y;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

x = atoi(argv[1]);
y = atoi(argv[2]);

printf("%d,%d\n",x,y);
}
```

Try this, the MPI consider arguments after program name so use 1 and 2 as argument.

Comment: this was already answered in the comment section 7 years ago.

Comment: still useful to elevate to an answer, indeed this is recommended.